# Spring set property after creation of spring bean from spring context

Tags: spring

I have a spring datasource as following, in core module with its own spring context i don't want to set maxActivetime

```
<bean id="wssModelDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbcx.JtdsDataSource"/>
    <property name="url" value="com.wss.jdbc.ConnectionUrl=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://x-x2/x_control_QA;appName=wss;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false;loginTimeout=20;socketTimeout=180"/>
    <property name="username" value="xxx"/>
    <property name="password" value="xxx"/>
  </bean>
```

I have dependent module which depends upon core module which have its own spring context and in this component i want to set datasource maxIdle time

```
<property name="wssModelDataSource.maxIdle" value="40"/>
```

and there are many other modules which also depend upon wssModelDataSource but i dno't want to change maxIdle time for them.

my question is if i put `<property name="wssModelDataSource.maxIdle" value="40"/>` at the root of spring context file it gives me error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<bean class="com.wss.spring.DataSourcePropertyOverrider" >
    <property name="maxIdle" value="#{com.wss.jdbc.MaximumIdleConnections}"/>
    <property name="minIdle" value="#{com.wss.jdbc.MinimumIdleConnections}"/>
    <property name="initialSize" value="#{com.wss.jdbc.InitConnectionSize}"/>
      </bean>
```

Create BeanFactoryPostProcessor implementation and override postProcessBeanFactory method

```
public class DataSourcePropertyOverrider implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

    private int maxIdle;
    private int minIdle;
    private int initialSize ;
    /**
     *
     * @param beanFactory
     * @throws BeansException
     */
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        BasicDataSource dataSource  = (BasicDataSource)beanFactory.getBean("wssModelDataSource");

        if(dataSource != null){
            dataSource.setMaxIdle(maxIdle);
            dataSource.setMinIdle(minIdle);
            dataSource.setInitialSize(initialSize);
        }

        //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }


    public int getMaxIdle() {
        return maxIdle;
    }

    public void setMaxIdle(int maxIdle) {
        this.maxIdle = maxIdle;
    }

    public void setMinIdle(int minIdle) {
        this.minIdle = minIdle;
    }

    public int getMinIdle() {

        return minIdle;
    }

    public int getInitialSize() {
        return initialSize;
    }

    public void setInitialSize(int initialSize) {
        this.initialSize = initialSize;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can instead do this:

Define an abstract base bean with common props:

```
<bean id="baseDatasource" abstract="true" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbcx.JtdsDataSource"/>
    <property name="url" value="com.wss.jdbc.ConnectionUrl=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://x-x2/x_control_QA;appName=wss;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false;loginTimeout=20;socketTimeout=180"/>
    <property name="username" value="xxx"/>
    <property name="password" value="xxx"/>

  </bean>
```

Now define your child datasources off this, with specific modifications as needed:

```
<bean id="wssModelDataSource" parent="baseDatasource">
    <property name="maxIdle" value="40">
</bean>
```